# Prevent Visual Studio from getting sources from TFS twice

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Once a new branch is mapped the sources are retrieved for the first time from TFS. But when a solution file from the sources just retrieved is opened for the first time it gets all the sources once again. With a pretty large solutions when each attempt may take about an hour it is rather annoying.
**Note:** The behavior is reproduced not only for me but for all members of the team and reproduces for a long time for VS 2010, previous version VS 2008 and if I am not mistaken the same issue was with VS 2005. Not sure is it Visual Studio or TFS that is to blame.

After these long unhappy years I am eventually sick and tired of the issue and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hmm, this is definitely not by design.  A few questions: 1. Do you happen to have the "Get Latest On Checkout" option enabled?  This can be viewed in Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Source Control > Visual Studio Team Foundation Server.  The option text will read "Get latest version of item on check-out...". 2. When you open the solution are you checking out the entire solution? 3. Do all of the files re-download?

Comment: 1. Get latest version of item on check out:  not enabled 2. No  3. Do not know how to determine whether all files are re-downloaded. But it takes the same amount of time  - in my particular case almost half an hour - that's why it is so annoying.

Comment: Can you check for the solution under File -> source control -> workspaces that the source control bindings are exactly the same as your team configuration setting. Sometimes dns alliasses ands machine renames can get in the way of this meganism. A simple unbind, bind for each project should clear that up (and checking-in the sln file in ofcours).

Comment: The bindings (located btw under File -> Source Sontrol -> Change Source Control) are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me the next was helpful: go to Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Environment -> uncheck checkbox "Get everything when a solution or project is opened"

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it is not my case. The setting is not enabled.